# Whitespace got removed on unmarshalling from JAXB-CXF

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb

As per our requirement, we have to keep the white space in our xml output, the xml is created using the xslt and the white space is returned to JAX B, for example,

```
<code>test</code>
  <value> </value>
```

But when this is processed by JAXB unmarshaller, we are losing the white space, is there any way where we can get the XML with white space

Thank you in advance

Regards
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8")
```

before marshalling xml.

If this solution doesn't do the job you can write your own read filter.

source: https://recalll.co/app/?q=java%20-%20JAXB%20unmarshal%20deletes%20newline

```
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("src/forum22284324/input.xml"));
    xsr = xif.createFilteredReader(xsr, new StreamFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader reader) {
            if(reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS) {
                return reader.getText().trim().length() > 0;
            } 
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, just to update that it haven't worked for us now